# Как с помощью Clang собрать библиотеку из исходного кода на Windows

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, glfw

Что нужно сделать, чтобы получить статическую/динамическую GLFW (или любую другую, в которой имеются файлы makefile или/и cmakelists.txt) библиотеку 64-бит на ОС Windows 10 используя Clang? Мне нужно в итоге получить файлы .dll и статический (как .a в MinGW).

Comment: Вам нужны: clang, cmake и migwmake. При конфигурировании cmake задайте нужный генератор и компилятор. Потом запустите build. Все...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch какой генератор необходимо выбрать? И mingw-make я должен брать из репозитория с MinGW32 или новым MinGW w64?

Comment: migw64. Для migw генератор mingw makefiles, а для msvc - Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

Comment: migw64. Для migw генератор mingw makefiles, а для msvc - Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch т.е вы хотите сказать, что библиотеки собранные для MinGW также пойдут для Clang?

Comment: я извиняюсь, а где я писал что-то подобное?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch тогда я не вижу разницы в сборке библиотеки для MinGW и для Clang из того, что вы говорите и не ответили откуда/какой mingwmake я должен использовать

Comment: вы ведь понимаете, что mingwmake - это не компилятор?